# Encerrar laço ao digitar caracter específico

Tags: c, lógica, while, for

Olá! 
Preciso resolver a seguinte questão, porém não estou conseguindo.

Escreva um algoritmo que calcule a média 
aritmética das 3 notas dos alunos (número 
indeterminado de alunos) de uma classe. O 
algoritmo deverá ler, além das notas, o código do 
aluno e deverá ser encerrado quando o código for 
igual a zero

Escrevi o código abaixo, não sei o que está errado, pois quando "codigo = 0" ele não encerra. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
main()
{

int codigo, n1, n2, n3, i;
float media;


while(codigo != 0){
    for(i= 0; i >= 0; i++){
            printf("Digite o código do aluno:\n");
            scanf("%d", &codigo);
            printf("Digite as 3 notas do aluno:\n");
            scanf("%d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3);
            media = ((n1+n2+n3)/3);
            printf("Media = %.2f\n", media);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você não precisa do bloco `for`, note que você declara `i` e a variável não é usada dentro do bloco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linha com o `for` esta errada.

Note que nele esta escrito `for(i= 0; i >= 0; i++)`, que significa:

> para i de 0, enquanto i > = 0, incrementando i em uma unidade por ciclo, execute...

Ou seja, como sua variável `i` é inicializada com `0`, e ela é sempre incrementada, ela nunca será *menor que 0*, portanto este `for` nunca será finalizado.

Na verdade, não há, se quer, motivo para ele (ao menos de acordo com a especificação do exercício citado), podendo assim ser removido.

```
main() {
    int codigo, n1, n2, n3;
    float media;

    while(codigo != 0){
        printf("Digite o código do aluno:\n");
        scanf("%d", &codigo);
        printf("Digite as 3 notas do aluno:\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3);
        media = ((n1+n2+n3)/3);
        printf("Media = %.2f\n", media);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Outro fator que deve ser observado, é que quando digita-se `0` para o código do aluno, não queremos que as notas sejam lidas (já que não estamos associando-as com um aluno). Lemos então as notas apenas se o código for diferente de 0 (`codigo != 0`).

```
main() {
    int codigo, n1, n2, n3;
    float media;

    while(codigo != 0){
        printf("Digite o código do aluno:\n");
        scanf("%d", &codigo);
        if ( codigo != 0 ) {
            printf("Digite as 3 notas do aluno:\n");
            scanf("%d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3);
            media = ((n1+n2+n3)/3);
            printf("Media = %.2f\n", media);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Na verdade, revi meu código e se ele for feito da forma como foi citado primeiramente, ele não vai nem iniciar, pois não tem nenhum dado de entrada antes do while. Ficou dessa forma:
    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
 int codigo, n1, n2, n3;
 float media;

 printf("Digite o código do aluno:\n");
 scanf("%d", &codigo);
 while(codigo !=0){ 
  printf("Digite as 3 notas do aluno:\n");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3);
  media = ((n1+n2+n3)/3);
  printf("Media = %.2f\n", media);
  printf("Digite o código do aluno:\n");
        scanf("%d", &codigo);
 }
 return 0;
}

Comment: @AndressaOliveira bem observado! Eu se quer havia notado este detalhe! Outra opção, se quiser, é inicializar `codigo` com qualquer valor diferente de zero, assim ele entrará no loop, e você não precisará duplicar código. Mas sua solução é igualmente válida.